# preg_match_all /(\w ):[^\/]/ not work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i want to get this pattern from my url : `(\w+):[^\/]+`
but it doesn;t work in PHP :(

in this url string : `http://azera/admin/filemanager/index/cmd:download/file:RjpcYXplcmFcUm91dGVyLnhtbA==`

i must get this array :

```
array (size=2)
  'cmd' => string 'download'
  'file' => string 'RjpcYXplcmFcUm91dGVyLnhtbA=='
```

but php returns null !
my php code :

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+):[^\/]+/',$url,$passedArgs);              // get passedArgs
```

how i can fix this ?

Comment: Seems to work fine to me

Comment: You might want to wrap the `[^\/]+` between brackets instead of `\w+`.

Comment: with `\w+` php cant get `==` at the end of args

Comment: i fix it by change `[^\/]+` to `([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by `null!`, but you want to get the array:

```
array (size=2)
  'cmd' => string 'download'
  'file' => string 'RjpcYXplcmFcUm91dGVyLnhtbA=='
```

while your regex: `(\w+):[^\/]+` is capturing `cmd` and `file`. You need to change the regex to:

```
\w+:([^\/]+)
```